# Rails redirection action: index, not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm looking for a solution.
I'm trying to redirect users when they are not an admin.

I've done that :

```
  def is_admin?
    if current_user.admin?
      redirect_to action: "index"
    else
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
```

I have `before_action :is_admin?` in my `posts_controller`

I dunno why exactly, but the redirection not working. Firefox gives me a blank page with:

> The page is not redirected correctly

Thanks for your help

Comment: What’s in the log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your `before_action :is_admin?` which call `is_admin?` on index methods and keep redirecting on themself...

I don't understand why redirecting on 'index', you should instead change your method `is_admin?` like :

```
  def is_admin?
    # redirect ONLY if user isn't admin
    redirect_to root_path unless current_user.admin?
  end
```

Comment: I'm learning Rails, i'm not really god at this moment, thank you very much for your help !